# Turn a sync API method to async?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

**Introduction:**
I'm trying to create a simple app that transcribes whatever audio is playing (i.e to help deaf people with content that doesn't have subtitles).

**Problem:** The app takes about a second to make a request to google servers to transcribe the audio, and because the code is synchronous, it will miss whatever words that are said while the app is getting the results.

**What I'm trying to achieve:** I thought if I can turn the transcribe method into async, then maybe I would be able to make the app listen to audio even while the app is making a request to the server to transcribe the previous sentence.

**My question**: The recognize_google method which is part of speech recognition is a sync method, is there a way to turn this into an async?

What I've tried:

```
import asyncio
import aioify
import speech_recognition as sr
import time


def listen(mic, r):
    print("Listening...", end="\r")
    with mic as source:
        audio = r.listen(source, timeout=3, phrase_time_limit=2)
        return audio


async def transcribe(audio, r):
    print("Transcribing...", end="\r")
    try:
        s = time.perf_counter()
        print(await r.recognize_google(audio))
        elapsed = time.perf_counter() - s
        print(f"{__file__} executed in {elapsed:0.2f} seconds.")
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("...", end="\r")


async def main():
    # while True:
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    r.pause_threshold = 1

    mic = sr.Microphone(device_index=2)
    audio = listen(mic, r)
    # transcribe(audio)
    await asyncio.gather(transcribe(audio, r))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        asyncio.run(main())
```

the error I got:

```
TypeError: object str can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Edit #1

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "speech_recogniation.py", line 37, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\Users\abodX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\abodX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 608, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "speech_recogniation.py", line 32, in main
    await asyncio.gather(transcribe(audio, r))
  File "speech_recogniation.py", line 17, in transcribe
    print(await r.recognize_google(audio))
TypeError: object str can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Comment: Please show the [complete traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough).

Comment: Updated the question to include complete traceback

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+call+synchronous+function+asynchronously

Comment: `asyncio.gather()` is supposed to receive **two** (or more) awaitables which it will then run in parallel. So even if `recognize_google()` were async, you would still not gain anything. Since none of the libraries you are using are async, you shouldn't try to use asyncio, but use threads instead. For example, you could have one thread that listens to the input, and hands off the audio to another thread (using a queue) that transcribes it. That way you could have them run completely independently of each other.

Comment: Thank you @user4815162342 will look into threads instead.