# How can I execute the button command asynchronously?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-asyncio, customtkinter

I'm trying to generate a transcription from an audio file using `pydub` and `speech_recognition` libraries. I'm trying to do this through a GUI made in Tkinter, in which I would like to show the transcription asynchronously. However, something doesn't work in my code because the GUI keeps freezing while generating the transcription.

Here is the code:

```
import customtkinter
import asyncio
from tkinter import filedialog
from async_tkinter_loop import async_handler, async_mainloop
import speech_recognition as sr
import os
from pathlib import Path
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.silence import split_on_silence


class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.filepath = None
        self.transcription = None

        self.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

        self.btn_select_file = customtkinter.CTkButton(
            self, text="Select audio file", command=self.open_file
        )
        self.btn_select_file.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=30)

        self.btn_generate_text = customtkinter.CTkButton(
            self,
            fg_color="green",
            text="Generate text",
            command=async_handler(self.get_transcription)
        )
        self.btn_generate_text.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=30)

        self.tbx_transcription = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(self, wrap="word")
        self.tbx_transcription.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="nsew")

    def open_file(self):
        # Open the file dialog
        filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename(
            initialdir="/",
            title="Select a file",
            filetypes=[("Audio files", ["*.mp3", "*.wav", "*.ogg", "*.opus", "*.mpeg"])]
        )

        if filepath:
            self.filepath = filepath

    async def get_transcription(self):
        if not self.filepath:
            self.tbx_transcription.insert(
                "0.0",
                "Error: No audio file selected, please select one before generating text."
            )
            return

        # Create a task to get the transcription
        task = [asyncio.create_task(self.generate_transcription(self.filepath))]

        completed, pending = await asyncio.wait(task)
        self.transcription = [task.result() for task in completed]

        # Display the transcription
        self.tbx_transcription.insert("0.0", self.transcription)

    @staticmethod
    async def generate_transcription(filepath):
        """
        Splitting a large audio file into chunks
        and applying speech recognition on each of these chunks
        """
        # create a speech recognition object
        r = sr.Recognizer()

        # open the audio file using pydub
        content_type = Path(filepath).suffix

        if "wav" in content_type:
            sound = AudioSegment.from_wav(filepath)
        elif "ogg" in content_type or "opus" in content_type:
            sound = AudioSegment.from_ogg(filepath)
        elif "mp3" in content_type or "mpeg" in content_type:
            sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(filepath)

        # split audio sound where silence is 700 miliseconds or more and get chunks
        chunks = split_on_silence(
            sound,
            # experiment with this value for your target audio file
            min_silence_len=500,
            # adjust this per requirement
            silence_thresh=sound.dBFS - 14,
            # keep the silence for 1 second, adjustable as well
            keep_silence=500,
        )

        folder_name = "audio-chunks"
        # create a directory to store the audio chunks
        if not os.path.isdir(folder_name):
            os.mkdir(folder_name)

        whole_text = ""
        # process each chunk
        for i, audio_chunk in enumerate(chunks, start=1):
            # export audio chunk and save it in the `folder_name` directory.
            chunk_filename = os.path.join(folder_name, f"chunk{i}.wav")
            audio_chunk.export(chunk_filename, format="wav")
            # recognize the chunk
            with sr.AudioFile(chunk_filename) as source:
                audio_listened = r.record(source)
                # try converting it to text
                try:
                    text = r.recognize_google(audio_listened, language="es")
                except sr.UnknownValueError as e:
                    print("Error:", str(e))
                else:
                    text = f"{text.capitalize()}. "
                    whole_text += text

        # return the text for all chunks detected
        return whole_text


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    async_mainloop(app)
```

I tried to use `async_tkinter_loop` library out of desperation, but it's not mandatory to use it.

**EDIT**: I've tried httpSteve's solution but the GUI keeps freezing, just as the code that I've provided above. Here is a gif that represents the undisired behaviour of the app.
[image: app bad behaviour]

It may not be appreciated, but I try to move the window and click on the buttons without any response. The GUI won't respond until the transcription is generated.

Comment: It looks to me like the problem is what httpSteve said, but it has to do with a different function: `generate_transcription` contains no await expression.  Therefore when you make a task from it, and it begins to run, all event loop activity will be frozen until it finishes.

Comment: @PaulCornelius I've been diving deeper into this matter and it seems that the problem, as you said, is that `generate_transcription` contains no await expression. Then, I thought that the logical thing to do would be to use `text = r.recognize_google(audio_listened, language="es")` but `recognize_google` is not async. Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67133562/turn-a-sync-api-method-to-async) post, I suspect that using threads would be the best option in order to achieve the desired output, but I have yet to figure out how to use them in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally managed to prevent the GUI from freezing thanks to `threading`. The key here is to use

```
threading.Thread(
    target=lambda loop: loop.run_until_complete(self.async_get_transcription()),
    args=(asyncio.new_event_loop(),)
).start()
```

and passing `command=lambda: self.get_transcription()` when creating the `self.btn_generate_text` object.

Here is the fixed code:

```
import asyncio
import customtkinter
import threading
from tkinter import filedialog
import speech_recognition as sr
import os
from pathlib import Path
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.silence import split_on_silence


class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.filepath = None
        self.transcription = None

        self.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

        self.btn_select_file = customtkinter.CTkButton(
            self,
            text="Select audio file",
            command=self.open_file
        )
        self.btn_select_file.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=30)

        self.btn_generate_text = customtkinter.CTkButton(
            self,
            fg_color="green",
            text="Generate text",
            command=lambda: self.get_transcription()
        )
        self.btn_generate_text.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=30)

        self.tbx_transcription = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(self, wrap="word")
        self.tbx_transcription.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="nsew")

    def open_file(self):
        # Open the file dialog
        filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename(
            initialdir="/",
            title="Select a file",
            filetypes=[("Audio files", ["*.mp3", "*.wav", "*.ogg", "*.opus", "*.mpeg"])]
        )

        if filepath:
            self.filepath = filepath

    def get_transcription(self):
        if not self.filepath:
            self.tbx_transcription.insert(
                "0.0",
                "Error: No audio file selected, please select one before generating text."
            )
            return

        threading.Thread(
            target=lambda loop: loop.run_until_complete(self.async_get_transcription()),
            args=(asyncio.new_event_loop(),)
        ).start()

        self.progressbar_1 = customtkinter.CTkProgressBar(self)
        self.progressbar_1.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=40, pady=0, sticky="ew")
        self.progressbar_1.configure(mode="indeterminnate")
        self.progressbar_1.start()

    async def async_get_transcription(self):
        self.transcription = await self.generate_transcription(self.filepath)
        self.progressbar_1.grid_forget()
        self.tbx_transcription.insert("0.0", self.transcription)

    @staticmethod
    async def generate_transcription(filepath):
        """
        Splitting a large audio file into chunks
        and applying speech recognition on each of these chunks
        """
        # create a speech recognition object
        r = sr.Recognizer()

        # open the audio file using pydub
        content_type = Path(filepath).suffix

        if "wav" in content_type:
            sound = AudioSegment.from_wav(filepath)
        elif "ogg" in content_type or "opus" in content_type:
            sound = AudioSegment.from_ogg(filepath)
        elif "mp3" in content_type or "mpeg" in content_type:
            sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(filepath)

        # split audio sound where silence is 700 miliseconds or more and get chunks
        chunks = split_on_silence(
            sound,
            # experiment with this value for your target audio file
            min_silence_len=500,
            # adjust this per requirement
            silence_thresh=sound.dBFS - 14,
            # keep the silence for 1 second, adjustable as well
            keep_silence=500,
        )

        folder_name = "audio-chunks"
        # create a directory to store the audio chunks
        if not os.path.isdir(folder_name):
            os.mkdir(folder_name)

        whole_text = ""
        # process each chunk
        for i, audio_chunk in enumerate(chunks, start=1):
            # export audio chunk and save it in the `folder_name` directory.
            chunk_filename = os.path.join(folder_name, f"chunk{i}.wav")
            audio_chunk.export(chunk_filename, format="wav")
            # recognize the chunk
            with sr.AudioFile(chunk_filename) as source:
                audio_listened = r.record(source)
                # try converting it to text
                try:
                    text = r.recognize_google(audio_listened, language="es")
                except sr.UnknownValueError as e:
                    print("Error:", str(e))
                else:
                    text = f"{text.capitalize()}. "
                    whole_text += text

        # return the text for all chunks detected
        return whole_text


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```